# How to use firestore field incremental using python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to increment and update a firestore field in Python.
Seems like incremental feature is added in recently google-cloud-firestore 1.2.0 . [issue-7533](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7533)! How can this be implemented in python? Any sample implementation reference code will be really helpful.

```
from google.cloud import firestore
......
upd_ref_path.update({u'test_col': firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
```

I got following error message
error: AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.firestore' has no attribute 'FieldValue'

UPDATE -

This feature needs an enchantment to use if from firestore module. Issue - 
[issue-8173](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8173)!
 is opened for this.

For temp solution use as below:

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import Increment
doc_ref.set({u'test_col': Increment(1)}, merge=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/transforms.html). You should be able to use it like:

```py
from google.cloud import firestore
......
upd_ref_path.update({u'test_col': firestore.transforms.Increment(1)})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I tried the above, it doesn't seem to invoke correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're importing from `firebase_admin` it should be like this

```
washington_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'DC')

washington_ref.update({"population": firestore.Increment(50)})
```

Check [docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-numeric-increment) for more info.